# Linq order by ascending sort by descending

Tags: c#, mysql, sorting, linq-to-entities

Sorry for title, but i didn't know how to write it better. I will try in post.

When I am trying to get values from database using linq with orderby something strange happens. Let's look on 4 queries:

```
//1
var badAsc = new ConcurrentBag<int>((from x in se.produkts orderby x.numerProduktu select x.numerProduktu));
//2                        
var bagDesc = new ConcurrentBag<int>((from x in se.produkts orderby x.numerProduktu descending select x.numerProduktu));
//3
var listAsc = (from x in se.produkts orderby x.numerProduktu select x.numerProduktu).ToList();
//4
var listdesc = (from x in se.produkts orderby x.numerProduktu descending select x.numerProduktu).ToList();
```

We got 2 `ConcurrentBags<int>` and 2 `List<int>`. What I was expecting from this is that 1 and 3 will be the same and also 2 and 4 will be the same. Check what values i got:

[image: linq queries]

Ascending sort for `ConcurrentBag<int>` is in fact descending. On Microsoft site we can read, that `ConcurrentBag` is good when sorting does not matters, but as we can see in `bagDesc`, sorting is kept. To show, that I don't have any strange things in database I also make two `List<int>` where sorting is kept as it should be.

Executing `select * from produkt` in my database gives me values sorted like `listAsc` and `bagDesc`.

Database is `mssql 2014` and `numerProduktu` is primary key in this table.

Do anybody know what happened there?

Comment: MSDN `ConcurrentBag<T>`: *"Represents a thread-safe, **unordered** collection of objects."*. The order in this collection type is unspecified. The behavior you're observing is coincidental.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: When used in multiple Threads, here the contsructor is used. So the behavior is deterministic.

Comment: @Frederick it may be deterministic today, but my point is that since it's documented as being unordered, the implementation could change anytime in a future version of the framework. You shouldn't rely on undocumented behavior.

Comment: I think adding in one thread always will be deterministic, because ConcurrentBag is using few lists, one for each thread. In one thread, easiest way to insert values is deterministic. I don't think this will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](http://informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=842).

> The ConcurrentBag appears to be implemented as a stack rather than a
>   queue. That is, the last item added is the first item removed. I
>   wouldn't count on that, though.

So they are getting added in reverse order. However, order is not meant to be reliably consistent in [`ConcurrentBag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx), so it's not guaranteed to always behave that way, especially if accessed by multiple threads.

If you care about maintaining the original order of entry, then you probably want a [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Source at [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/ConcurrentBag.cs,bee2e1ab2eac325c).

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. Thank you! I didn't even taught about stack. This information should appear at msdn site, i think. I know that `ConcurrentBag` is not good when sorting matters, as I mentioned this in my post and I don't care about original order. This post was from my curiosity :)